# iPad app rejection because of not supporting orientation. How to resolve issues?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

My iPad app gets rejected with following reason-

> The iPad Human Interface Guidelines state that an iPad application should be
>   able to run in all orientations. XXXX is only
>   supporting one variant of the portrait orientation.  While we understand
>   there are certain applications that need to run in the portrait orientation,
>   it would be appropriate to support both variants of this orientation in your
>   application.

Where I have supported all the 4 orientation. Has any one got similar type of issues and how you have delved with it?

Checked application on using base sdk 3.2 rotates well on all orientations but when i used base sdk 4.2 rotation gets stopped even application hangs..! Not getting any clue, Please help!

Found That following method in viewWillAppear not working properly results viewWillAppear gets stuck in loop!

```
appDelegate.splitViewController.viewControllers = 
[NSArray arrayWithObjects:appDelegate.navScreenObj, appDelegate.ScreenObj2, nil];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checked the application on xcode 3.2.5, simulator 4.2, found that application getting hanged during rotation. Actually it is getting stuck in loop so why felling to rotate.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your app supports all the orientations in all of your views.

Comment: hmm... In info.plist i have supported all 4 orientation also in all uiviewcontroller subclasses my shouldAutoRotate function returns Yes. So any other guess..

Comment: this is not a guess, it is the right answer.  Supporting rotation is not as easy as setting a few flags.  You have to implement it and tell the views how to resize etc.  I would read up on it in the docs

Comment: Oh ya, you accept an answer by clicking the big check next to the post.  Start there.

Comment: Ya i know this is the correct answer but that is not which i am looking for. I have checked my application on device, it rotates well on  all orientation. so why i gets frustrating after rejection by app store on issue of supporting only single variants of orientation.

Comment: It is the only answer. If you think Apple made a mistake (which I doubt), you can send an appeal to their review board. But I would start by double-checking that your app rotates correctly in all orientations. The way you describe their feedback, you have not implement UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown correctly.

Comment: but what apple mean- XXXX is only supporting one variant of the portrait orientation? Actually in shouldAutoRotate method i have made some layout changes based on device orientation and it returns YES. So is my one of view has a trouble or whole app?

Comment: I don't know. But they are saying that somewhere in your app you don't support both "UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait" and "UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown". Now go and start accepting some answers on Stackoverflow.

Comment: ok thanks i will check that. How to accept answers, i dont know really.

Answer (score 0):

To expand upon what Joseph said, make sure that the `UISupportedInterfaceOrientations` key in your Info.plist includes both `UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait` and `UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown`.

Additionally, when checking for supported orientations in your view controllers' `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` methods, make sure you use the `UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait()` macro to test the orientation, because it checks both portrait variations.

If you can, also add support to your application for both landscape orientations in this manner.

Comment: hello Brad Larson, UISupportedInterfaceOrientations key in my app  Info.plist includes all 4 orientations UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait and UIOPortraitUpsideDown, UIOLandscapeRight and UIOLandscapeLeft. Also my app includes subclasses of UIViewController, UIView, UIImageView also UIScrollView and those subclasses overrides shouldAutoRotate method which returns YES, yet my app gets rejected by giving reason mentioned above in que. So i confused. Any  other idea why this happened? Thanks..

Comment: @Mahesh - Does the application start in all orientations when you test it on the device or in the Simulator?  Does it properly autorotate to each orientation in each screen on both?  Even a single UIViewController that responds NO to an orientation in `-shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:` can prevent the entire interface from rotating.

Comment: I have tested it on device and it rotates in all direction. May be it gets hanged on particular condition so why they rejected it?

Comment: @Mahesh - Does it start properly in all orientations?  There might also be a condition where it doesn't rotate properly in response to some view controller appearing onscreen.  Also, make sure that you have proper Default.png images for both landscape and portrait orientations.

Comment: @Brad Larson - It starts properly in all rotation. Actually my rejected app didnt contain launch images but now i have used Default-Landscape.png and Default-Portrait.png files and app is uploaded again. Hope this time they wont reject it.

Comment: @Brad Larson - However these Launch images are recommended but not compulsory..!

Comment: @Mahesh - For a while, they had been rejecting applications that did not have the proper default launch images.  It's a good practice, anyway, because it improves the user experience.